# ¿Como quitar espacios entre div con css o Jquery?

Tags: html, jquery, css

He estado intentando quitar el espacio que se forma entre las filas de los cuadros. Esto es lo que he intentado.

He intentado solo ponerle border:1 px solid black y sigue sin tomar la forma que me gustaria. Quiero que quede la cuadricula sin esa doble linea que se observa.

```js
var div = document.getElementById("click");
guessX = 0;
guessY = 0;

function capturaCoor(event) {
  var x = event.offsetX;
  var y = event.offsetY;
  guessX = x;
  guessY = y;
  console.log("x coords: " + guessX + ", y coords: " + guessY);
}
var i, j;
for (i = 0; i < 525; i++) {
  $("#click").prepend($('<div class="re"></div>'));
}
$(".re:odd").css("background-color", "white");
```

```css
body,
html {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.re {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background-color: black;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
  border-top: 1px solid;
}

.re:hover {
  background-color: red;
}

#click {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="click" onclick="capturaCoor(event)"></div>
```

Saludos!

Comment: esta bien como formas esos divs?

Comment: @SebastiánLagosYañez No sé, crees que hay una mejor forma?

Comment: lo que pasa que no cerraste la etiquerda div aca mira `('<div class="re"</div>'));`

Comment: @SebastiánLagosYañez Lo cerre y sigue igual.

Comment: mira lo curioso @Luis Fernando `height: 20px;` ponlo asi en el re `height: auto;`

Comment: tiene razón @SebastiánLagosYañez, pon los bordes en 0 px y height en auto.

Comment: te hago la respuesta ahora mira lo que logre.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

En tu caso esta definiendo las alturas, por lo tanto
se resuelve de la siguiente manera solo colocando en el `#click` el `height: auto;` y quitando los border de la clase `.re`

```js
var div = document.getElementById("click");
guessX = 0;
guessY = 0;

function capturaCoor(event) {
  var x = event.offsetX;
  var y = event.offsetY;
  guessX = x;
  guessY = y;
  console.log("x coords: " + guessX + ", y coords: " + guessY);
}
var i, j;
for (i = 0; i < 525; i++) {
  $("#click").prepend($('<div class="re"></div>'));
}
$(".re:odd").css("background-color", "white");
```

```css
body,
html {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.re {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background-color: black;
  cursor: pointer;

}

.re:hover {
  background-color: red;
}

#click {
  width: 500px;
  height: auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="click" onclick="capturaCoor(event)"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Agregando al contenedor `align-content: baseline;` debería justificar los elementos.

```js
var div = document.getElementById("click");
guessX = 0;
guessY = 0;

function capturaCoor(event) {
  var x = event.offsetX;
  var y = event.offsetY;
  guessX = x;
  guessY = y;
  console.log("x coords: " + guessX + ", y coords: " + guessY);
}
var i, j;
for (i = 0; i < 525; i++) {
  $("#click").prepend($('<div class="re"></div>'));
}
$(".re:odd").css("background-color", "white");
```

```css
body,
html {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.re {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background-color: black;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
  border-top: 1px solid;
}

.re:hover {
  background-color: red;
}

#click {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: baseline;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="click" onclick="capturaCoor(event)"></div>
```

---

Si querés aprender más a cómo utilizar flex, te recomiendo que pruebes con [esta página](https://flexboxfroggy.com/#es) para principiantes que te explican bastante bien y con un juego.

Answer (score 1):

le puedes quitar la altura. También al crear tus DIVS estaban mal cerrados.

Saludos

```js
var div = document.getElementById("click");
guessX = 0;
guessY = 0;

function capturaCoor(event) {
  var x = event.offsetX;
  var y = event.offsetY;
  guessX = x;
  guessY = y;
  console.log("x coords: " + guessX + ", y coords: " + guessY);
}
var i, j;
for (i = 0; i < 525; i++) {
  $("#click").prepend($('<div class="re"></div>'));
}
$(".re:odd").css("background-color", "white");
```

```css
body,
html {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.re {
  width: 20px;
  background-color: black;
  cursor: pointer;
  
}

.re:hover {
  background-color: red;
}

#click {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="click" onclick="capturaCoor(event)"></div>
```